# Flutter download file in phone storage

Tags: flutter, download

I am not able to download file in the phone storage.. My code is..

```
Future<void> downloadFile() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    bool checkPermission1 =
        await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(permission1);
    print('checkPermission1');
    print(checkPermission1);
    if (checkPermission1 == false) {
      await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(permission1);
      checkPermission1 = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(permission1);
    } 
     
    if (checkPermission1 == true) {
      String dirloc = "";
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        dirloc = "/sdcard/downloads/";
      } else {
        dirloc = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      }

      try {
        FileUtils.mkdir([dirloc]);
        await dio.download(url, dirloc + id + ".mp4",
            onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
          setState(() {
            downloadingFlag = true;
            progress =
                ((receivedBytes / totalBytes) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
          });
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }

      setState(() {
        downloadingFlag = false;
        downloadsFlag = false;
        progress = "Download Completed.";
        path = dirloc + id + ".mp4";
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        progress = "Permission Denied!";
      });
    }
  }
```

I/flutter (23004): FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/sdcard/downloads' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Comment: `   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` try adding these permissions to the manifest. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE this link would help you more.

Comment: I have already added that in manifest file.´´´<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>´´´